# Using method sub to transform a string with a var type '$'

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to modify a string as follows:

```
"one hundred forty-four".sub(/(\w+)(\s)([a-z\-]+)$/){$2 =  "test"}

say.rb:78: Can't set variable $2
```

How can I do that?

edit: `one hundredtestforty-four` is what i want.

Comment: Is this what you want: `"one hundred forty-four".sub(/[a-z-]+$/, "test") => "one hundred test"`? When you give an example, please always show your desired output.

Comment: sorry, my post is not very explicit

Comment: ```one hundredtestforty-four``` is what i want.

Comment: When you clarify a question, you should do so by editing, rather than trying to explain in comments. (Add, don't delete, and where appropriate, identify edits as such.)  I suggest you do that here, in part to avoid more downvotes.  When you have time, give this [SO faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help) a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
"one hundred forty-four".sub(/\s+([a-z-]+)$/, 'test\1')
  #=> "one hundredtestforty-four"
```

or

```
"one hundred forty-four".sub(/\s+([a-z-]+)$/, "test\\1")
  #=> "one hundredtestforty-four"
```

or

```
"one hundred forty-four".sub(/\s+([a-z-]+)$/, "test"+$1)
  #=> "one hundredtestforty-four"
```

or

```
"one hundred forty-four".sub(/\s+([a-z-]+)$/, "test#{$1}")
  #=> "one hundredtestforty-four"
```

The regex looks for a string that starts with one or more spaces, then any number of lowercase letters or hypens, followed by an end-of-line. (Note the hypen is not escaped within a character class, and it must be appear first or last within the class). It therefore matches `" forty-four"`, with capture group 1 containing `"forty-four"`.  Ergo, `" forty-four"` is replaced with `"testforty-four"`. Notice that you retrieve the contents of capture group 1 by writing `\1` if the string is written with single quotes, `\\1` if double-quotes are used. Alternatively, you can use the global variable in one of two ways shown.

Note that, if desired, you can use `$1` to reference the contents of capture group 1 in subsequent statements.

Comment: what represent ```\1``` the match ? as $1 ?

Comment: I edited to address your (pertinent) question.

Answer (score 2):

It is not allowed. It is a read only global variable.

Using another global variable name it works fine.

Of course, using global variables bring concerns of clobbering other parts of your program.